# gitignore correct path for ASP.NET solution

Tags: asp.net, git

I have an ASP.NET solution with one MVC project in it.

Lets call

- the path of my .sln file is the root-folder.
- the path of my .csproj file is the MyProject-folder

I added the gitignore file from within VS2019:
Team Eplorer -> Repository Settings -> Ignore File -> Add

The gitignore file was created in the root-folder, as expected.

But on any build, the files of the obj and bin folder were found as changes.

I tried to move gitignore file inside the MyProject-folder, so then bin/obj files were correctly ignored. BUT git started tracking root-folder/.vs/* files, which is not wanted off course.

What would be the correct place for the gitignore file?

Comment: Have you added those files to the repo *before* creating the `.gitignore` file? Adding a `.gitignore` file won't remove any files already in the repo.

Comment: which files? the dll build files in bin? yes.. probably.. i am now checking the solution you suggest.